# Is there a category of "chains of modules" that behaves well with taking direct limits?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modules, limits-and-colimits

I came up with the following definition of a category of certain "chains of modules" and want to know if this concept is already known and studied.

Let $R$ be ring. An object in our category consists of $R$-modules $M_n$ for all natural numbers $n$ and morphisms $f_n^m : M_n \longrightarrow M_m$ for all $n\leq m$ with the following property: $f_n^n = 1_{M_n}$ and $f_n^m = f_k^m f_n^k$ for all $n\leq k \leq m$. We write $(M,f)$ for such a collection. Now we want to describe a morphism $(M,f) \longrightarrow (N,g)$. Consider a monotone map $\sigma: \mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and morphisms $\varphi_n : M_n\longrightarrow N_{\sigma(n)}$ for all natural numbers $n$. Further for all $n\leq m$ we demand $\varphi_m f_n^m = g_{\sigma(n)}^{\sigma(m)} \varphi_n$. We write $(\sigma,\varphi)$ for such a data. We define an equivalence relation via $(\sigma,\varphi) \sim (\tau, \psi)$ if for all natural numbers $n$ we find $m \geq \sigma(n),\tau(n)$ such that $g_{\sigma(n)}^m\varphi_n = g_{\tau(n)}^m \varphi_n$. A morphism $(M,f) \longrightarrow (N,g)$ is given by an equivalence class $[(\sigma,\varphi)]$ and composition is defined the obvious way. One can show that:

1. Everything is well-defined.
2. We have an additive category.
3. We have kernals. I am not sure wether cokernals always exist and if we are always abelian.
4. We have enough projectives.
5. Taking the direct limit over the modules $M_n$ with the morphisms $f_n^m$ yields a functor with "nice" properties. This was the motivation of all definitions.

Notice, I could have made a mistake in proving 1-5.

Comment: is this maybe equivalent to $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathrm{Mod}_R)$? the latter allows for any filtered diagram, but this seems pretty close since any of those receives a final map from the natural numbers, so it seems like you get an essentially surjective functor and you've defined an equivalence relation to ensure it's fully faithful. (but maybe I'm missing something)

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not familiar with the notion $\text{Ind}(\text{Mod}_R)$. I could not find it via google. Can you explain me what exactly it is? Thanks alot!

Comment: sorry, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ind-completion , and here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object

Comment: I think it is rather a full subcategory of $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathrm{Mod}_R)$, namely, those presheaves on $\mathrm{Mod}_R$ that are sequential colimits of representables (not every filtered diagram admits a cofinal map from $\mathbb N$!). This category will have sequential colimits and finite limits computed in presheaves, and also finite colimits computed in $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathrm{Mod}_R)$ (e.g., levelwise pushouts), but probably not all filtered colimits.

Comment: Thanks already for both of your answers, I think this is what I am looking for and I will have to read up on it. In my specific case I am actually considering $\text{mod}\,A$ the category of finitely generated $A$-modules where $A$ is a finite dimensional $k$-Algebra. Also I only want to take direct limits over the natural numbers as an idex set. Does the "Ind-completion" behave well in this case? Is this particular example well-studied?

Comment: @MarcHoyois It seems to me that there might be a difference between the full subcategory *spanned* by sequential colimits, and the full subcategory *generated* under sequential colimits? I don't know whether the former is well-behaved?

Comment: @Z.M I did not check carefully but I think the former is closed under sequential colimits, hence there is no difference. By inductively choosing cofinal subsequences, one can make any sequence in that category "levelwise", and then consider the diagonal sequence.